# Modifying QGIS's quick finder plugin to select the feature after clicking on a search reasult

Tags: pyqgis

I wanted to modify the python code of the quick finder plugin so that it selects the feature being found. At the moment it goes to the location of the feature and shows a QgsRubberBand on it, but does not select the feature..

[image]

I don't know much of python. My approach:

[image]

I think the only thing reamining is to add the id of the selected feature as a parameter to cLayer.setSelectedFeature(). How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It took me a while to cover main plugin structures and I think, something like that may helps:

```
act_lyr = self.iface.activeLayer()
request = QgsFeatureRequest().setFilterExpression( u'"gid" = \'%s\'' % (str(item.name)) )
feat_iter = act_lyr.getFeatures(request)
feats_ids = [x.id() for x in feat_iter]
act_lyr.selectByIds(feats_ids)
```

It also needs an following import:

```
from qgis.core import QgsFeatureRequest
```

Paste that in "quickfinder/gui/finder_box.py" file and more precisely in "showItem" function (+/- 191 line). Should looks like this:

```
def showItem(self, item):
    if isinstance(item, ResultItem):
        self.result_model.setSelected(item, self.result_view.palette())
        geometry = self.transform_geom(item)

        ------new_part------
        act_lyr = self.iface.activeLayer()
        request = QgsFeatureRequest().setFilterExpression( u'"gid" = \'%s\'' % (str(item.name)) )
        feat_iter = act_lyr.getFeatures( request )
        feats_ids = [x.id() for x in feat_iter]
        act_lyr.selectByIds(feats_ids)
        --------------------

        self.rubber.reset(geometry.type())
        self.rubber.setToGeometry(geometry, None)
        self.zoom_to_rubberband()
        return
```

Two important things:
- it works only on active layer
- expression is based on specific field name, which in this case is 'gid'; adjust by yourself

It's not perfect, but should helps you to go futher easier :)

Comment: Glad to help :)